# How to draw small circles to display around the half circle?

Tags: flutter

How to draw small circles around the half circle like the picture.

[image]

```
  //method      
    Widget buildCircle() {
    return Container(
      //Container height
      height: 150,
      // margin
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 70, right: 70),
     //gradient color
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        gradient: RadialGradient(
          center: Alignment(-0.8, -0.6),
          colors: [
            Color.fromRGBO(153, 250, 10, 1),
            Color.fromRGBO(153, 240, 94, 1)
          ],
       //radius of a circle
          radius: 1.0,
        ),
       // border radius
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(160),
          topRight: Radius.circular(160),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    }
```

Comment: so the snippet is your best effort or the answer itself and image you are trying to get? It would be nice if you describe a little more.

Comment: i were able to code for the half circle, but i do not know how to draw small circles that surround the half circle

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. I hope this will help you.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

class CustomCirclePainter extends CustomPainter {
@override
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
Paint paint = Paint()
  ..color = Colors.blue
  ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

double centerX = size.width / 2;
double centerY = size.height / 2;
double radius = size.width / 2;

// Draw semi-circle
Rect rect = Rect.fromCircle(center: Offset(centerX, centerY), radius: radius);
canvas.drawArc(rect, pi, pi, true, paint);

// Draw small non-filled circles at the upper side of the semi-circle
int numberOfCircles = 15;
double angleIncrement = -pi / (numberOfCircles + 1);

for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfCircles; i++) {
  double angle = angleIncrement * i;
  double x = centerX + (radius + 20) * cos(angle);
  double y = centerY + (radius + 20) * sin(angle);

  canvas.drawCircle(Offset(x, y), 5, paint..style = PaintingStyle.stroke);
 }
 }

 @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
   return false;
 }
 }

 class SemiCircleWithCircles extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Center(
    child: CustomPaint(
     size: Size(200, 200), // Set your desired size
     painter: CustomCirclePainter(),
    ),
    );
  }
 }

void main() {
 runApp(MaterialApp(
 home: Scaffold(
   appBar: AppBar(
     title: Text('Semi Circle with Circles'),
   ),
   body: SemiCircleWithCircles(),
 ),
 ));
}
```

Output:

[image]